# How to make ./gradlew buld execute other terminal commands

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, javacc

I am building a gradle project which has a javacc parser file (i.e a file with .jj extension)
Therefore, to execute this .jj file we need to run 3 commands in the terminal as
javacc filename.jj
javac *.java
java parsername

However, I want to know how to edit the build.gradle, so that whenever the user enters ./gradlew build all the above mentioned commands would be automatically executed.

Comment: Did you consider using one of the available plugins listed in the [Gradle Plugin Portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=javacc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you consider declaring your own task to do so ?

```
task executeCMD(type:Exec) {
  workingDir '.'
  commandLine 'cmd', 'echo', 'Hello world!'
     doLast {
         println "Executed!"
     }
 }
```

Am not sure how to link with the build command , maybe [this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/make-build-dependson-custom-task/21571/2) can be helpful `build.dependsOn project(':ProjectName').task('build')` .